# Compiling problem possible due to wrong header being imported

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, folly

I have a doubt on how Xcode configures the build process (this is a custom react-native problem).

My main file looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PodsDummy_Pods_Project : NSObject
@end
@implementation PodsDummy_Pods_Project
@end
```

But when I'm compiling it, a issue happens:

`<...>/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly/folly/string.h:20:10: 'cstdarg' file not found`.

As far as I can see the problem is `<Simulator>/usr/include/strings.h` is including the `string.h` from a pod lib (`RCT-Folly`) instead of `<Simulator>/usr/include/string.h`.

```
//... more code
int  flsll(long long) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_7_0);
__END_DECLS

#include <string.h>.   //this line it's including the string.h from the wrong place
#endif
//... more code
```

What could cause that?

I already tried to remove Folly from the HEADER_SEARCH_PATH with no success. Also clear everything (Pods, build, cache, etc..)